# How to get ArrayList Value without Using request.setAttribute Send from Java class to Jsp Page

Tags: jsp, httprequest, jstl, httpsession

Attempting to send an ArrayList from java class to Jsp Page through Servlet. The returned values of ResultSet is passed on to a model object and this object is added to an ArrayList.
Java code Should not use in jsp page <% %> And Java should only return the RequestDipature Path (Eg: View.jsp).

//Java Class

```
@Override
    public String execute(Map<String, String> map){
        return "#";
    }



public List<Tour> showTour(){

        List<Tour> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "Select * from Tour";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while(resultSet.next()) {
                int tourId = resultSet.getInt("tourId");
                String tourCode = resultSet.getString("tourCode");
                String tourName = resultSet.getString("tourName");
                String boardingPlace = resultSet.getString("boardingPlace");
                String destinationPlace = resultSet.getString("destinationPlace");
                Tour tour = new Tour(tourId, tourCode, tourName, boardingPlace, destinationPlace);
                list.add(tour);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
                con.close();
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

//Jsp Page

```
<c:forEach var="tourList" items="${LIST_TOUR}">
    <tr>
        <td>${tourList.tourId}</td>
        <td>${tourList.tourCode}</td>
        <td>${tourList.tourName}</td>
        <td>${tourList.boardingPlace}</td>
        <td>${tourList.destinationPlace}</td>

    </tr>
```

//Servlet

```
protected void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException  {

        //Map Content Here

        String responsePath = command.execute(map);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(responsePath);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
```

Comment: Why exactly without using `request.setAttribute(...)`? Is this a homework?

Comment: No this is my project

Comment: You can do that using CDI (who will in turn still use `request.setAttribute(...)` etc under the covers, but you don't need to do it manually anymore). Do you have CDI available in your environment? If not (sure) then tell which environment exactly you're using. For example Tomcat doesn't have CDI built-in by default and then you'd have to manually install it. But a normal Java EE server has CDI already built-in, but it might need to be activated first depending on the server version.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the only way to pass parameter to jsp from servlet is by using **request.setAttribute(...)**.

**i will always do like this way**

```
protected void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException  {

        private static String VIEW= "/view.jsp";

        String forward = VIEW;
        request.setAttribute("LIST_TOUR",showTour());
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
```

Mind to elaborate why cannot use **request.setAttribute(...)**  ?

Cheers :)